# Comparing an Image to a background image to find an object using OpenCV with Java

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I have a project where I am trying to track a person as they move throughout a room.  I am using an arduino, some servo motors and an xbox kinect for my camera.

I have a vision of allowing the project some training time where it can scan the room and make a database of images for the empty  room.  Then when a person enters the room the program can do a simple difference image to create a white blob for the person.  Using this white blob I would be able to calculate the centre of mass for the person and compare it to the centre of the image frame in order to pass a command to the arduino telling it how far and in which direction to move the servo motors.  I am using eclipse, writing in java and using opencv 2.4.6.

I am stuck on getting a clear white blob.  I have already written my methods to calculate the distance from the centre of mass of the blob and the centre of the frame but without a clearly defined blob this is useless.  I have been trying to get my program to work by taking a snap shot of the background of my room, changing the image to binary then subtracting it from a binary image of my room with me in it.  This has not worked.  Is my vision of training the system then comparing with these trained images valid or should I be going about a different way to detect an object?

I have tried implementing opticalflow() but it seems erratic and not extremely accurate.

Any information on the topic would be extremely helpful.  I thank you in advance for reading my question.

-Trent

Edit: I have attached my code.  The area in question is the training() and matdiff() methods.

```
package testingV1;

//OpenCv + OpenNI + Java Libraries
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBuffer;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.imgproc.*;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;
import org.opencv.video.BackgroundSubtractorMOG;
import org.opencv.video.Video;
import org.opencv.highgui.*;
import org.opencv.*;
import org.OpenNI.*;

public class TestV1 {
    static int imWidth = 640, imHeight = 480;
    static ImageGenerator imageGen;
    static Context context;
    static int flag = CvType.CV_8UC3;
    static int flag2 = CvType.CV_8UC1;
    static Mat background;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralException{
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        //We create a new "context" of the Kinect
        context = new Context(); 
        JFrame canvas = new JFrame("Optical Flow");

        //need to create and add license to our "context"
        License license = new License("PrimeSense", "0KOIk2JeIBYClPWVnMoRKn5cdY4=");
        context.addLicense(license); 

        //defining the data we are taking from the kinect
        MapOutputMode mapMode = null; //initialize it to null
        mapMode = new MapOutputMode(imWidth, imHeight, 30); //create a 640x480 30fps feed definition

        imageGen = ImageGenerator.create(context); //Rgb camera
        imageGen.setMapOutputMode(mapMode); //change our feed to 640x480 30 fps
        imageGen.setPixelFormat(PixelFormat.RGB24);///Pixel format, RGB 8-bit 3 channel 


        context.setGlobalMirror(true); //Mirrors our feed to make it more intuitive

        BufferedImage rgbImage = new BufferedImage(imWidth, imHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        BufferedImage prevImg = new BufferedImage(imWidth, imHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        BufferedImage currImg = new BufferedImage(imWidth, imHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        BufferedImage diffImg = new BufferedImage(imWidth, imHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        BufferedImage paintedImg = new BufferedImage(imWidth, imHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        BufferedImage facesImg = new BufferedImage(imWidth, imHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Mat paintedMat = new Mat(imHeight, imWidth, flag);
        Mat facesMat = new Mat(imHeight, imWidth, flag);
        Mat currMat = new Mat(imHeight, imWidth, flag2);
        Mat prevMat = new Mat(imHeight, imWidth, flag2);
        Mat diffMat = new Mat(imHeight, imWidth, flag2);    
        Mat paintedMatg = new Mat(imHeight, imWidth, flag2);
        ByteBuffer imageBB;

        //First Frame
        canvas.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Icon video = new ImageIcon(rgbImage);
        JLabel panel = new JLabel(video);
        //Icon video2 = new ImageIcon(paintedImg);
        //JLabel panel2 = new JLabel(video2);
        //Icon video3 = new ImageIcon(facesImg);
        //JLabel panel3 = new JLabel(video3);
        Icon video4 = new ImageIcon(diffImg);
        JLabel panel4 = new JLabel(video4);
        canvas.getContentPane().add(panel);
        //canvas.getContentPane().add(panel2);
        //canvas.getContentPane().add(panel3);
        canvas.getContentPane().add(panel4);
        canvas.pack();
        canvas.setVisible(true);
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        CascadeClassifier faceDetectorAlg = new CascadeClassifier("C:/Users/Trent/Desktop/Capstone"
                + "/ComputerVisionCode/November16/testingV1/src/testingV1/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");

        boolean firstTime = true;

        imageGen.startGenerating();
        while(true){
            context.waitOneUpdateAll(imageGen);
            imageBB = imageGen.getImageMap().createByteBuffer(); //get KinectData
            rgbImage = bufToImage(imageBB);  //take data from kinect and put in BufferedImage
            prevMat = currMat;
            currMat = img2Mat(rgb2Gray(rgbImage));

            if(firstTime){
                training(rgbImage);
                firstTime = false;
            }
            else{

                diffMat = findDiff(currMat);
                diffImg = mat2Img(diffMat);
            }

            //optical flow - inaccurate
            //paintedMatg = opticalFlow(img2Mat(prevImg), img2Mat(currImg), 300, 0.01, 10);
            //Imgproc.cvtColor(paintedMatg, paintedMat, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB); //change from gray to color
            //paintedImg = mat2Img(paintedMat);

            //face detection - extremely resource intensive
            //facesMat = faceDetector(img2Mat(rgbImage), faceDetectorAlg);
            //facesImg = mat2Img(facesMat);

            panel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(rgbImage));
            //panel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(paintedImg));
            //panel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(facesImg));
            panel4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(diffImg));
            canvas.repaint();
            canvas.revalidate();
        }
    }

    //establishes a background for better diff images
    private static void training(BufferedImage in){
        background = new Mat(imHeight, imWidth, flag2);
        background = img2Mat(rgb2Gray(in));

        System.out.println("Training Complete");
    }

    private static Mat findDiff(Mat in){
        Mat output = new Mat(imHeight, imWidth, flag2);

        Core.absdiff(background, in, output);
        Imgproc.threshold(output, output, 20, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

        return output;
    }

    //Face Detection
    private static Mat faceDetector(Mat in, CascadeClassifier Alg){
        Mat output = in;
        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();

        if(Alg.empty()){
            System.out.println("didnt load");
            return output;
        }

        Alg.detectMultiScale(in, faceDetections);

        for(Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()){
            Core.rectangle(output,  new Point(rect.x, rect.y), 
                    new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
        }

        return output;
    }

    //Returns an image with vectors painted to show movement.
    private static Mat opticalFlow(Mat curr, Mat prev, int maxDetectionCount, double qualityLevel, double minDistance){
        List<MatOfPoint2f> trackedPoints = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint2f>();
        MatOfPoint initial = new MatOfPoint();
        MatOfFloat err = new MatOfFloat();
        MatOfByte status = new MatOfByte();
        MatOfPoint2f initial2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
        MatOfPoint2f next2f = new MatOfPoint2f();

        double[] temp;
        Point p1 = new Point();
        Point p2 = new Point();
        Mat output = new Mat(imHeight, imWidth, flag);

        Scalar red = new Scalar(255, 0, 0);

        //Finds Tracking points
        if(trackedPoints.size() < 1){
            Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(curr, initial, maxDetectionCount, qualityLevel, minDistance);
            initial.convertTo(initial2f, CvType.CV_32FC2);
            trackedPoints.add(initial2f);
        }

        //catches first time frame
        if(prev.empty())
            curr.copyTo(prev);

        //find points in current image
        if(trackedPoints.get(0).total() > 0){
            Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prev, curr, trackedPoints.get(0), next2f, status, err);
            trackedPoints.add(next2f);
        }

        output = curr;

        //draw red lines
        for(int i = 0; i < trackedPoints.get(0).cols(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < trackedPoints.get(0).rows(); j++){
                temp  = trackedPoints.get(0).get(j, i);
                p1.set(temp);
                temp = trackedPoints.get(1).get(j, i);
                p2.set(temp);
                Core.line(output, p1, p2, red);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }

    //Returns a vector to indicate how the magnitude of movement.
    private static double[] opticalFlowAnalysis(Mat curr, Mat prev, int maxDetectionCount, double qualityLevel, double minDistance){
        List<MatOfPoint2f> trackedPoints = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint2f>();
        MatOfPoint initial = new MatOfPoint();
        MatOfFloat err = new MatOfFloat();
        MatOfByte status = new MatOfByte();
        MatOfPoint2f initial2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
        MatOfPoint2f next2f = new MatOfPoint2f();

        double[] total = new double[2];
        total[0] = 0;
        total[1] = 0;
        double[] point1;
        double[] point2;

        double[] output = new double[2];

        //Finds Tracking points
        if(trackedPoints.size() < 1){
            Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(curr, initial, maxDetectionCount, qualityLevel, minDistance);
            initial.convertTo(initial2f, CvType.CV_32FC2);
            trackedPoints.add(initial2f);
        }

        //catches first time frame
        if(prev.empty())
            curr.copyTo(prev);

        //find points in current image
        if(trackedPoints.get(0).total() > 0){
            Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prev, curr, trackedPoints.get(0), next2f, status, err);
            trackedPoints.add(next2f);
        }

        //average the distance moved
        // (-) signifies distance moved right and down
        // (+) signifies distance moved left and up
        for(int i = 0; i < trackedPoints.get(0).cols(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < trackedPoints.get(0).rows(); j++){
                point1 = trackedPoints.get(0).get(j, i);
                point2 = trackedPoints.get(1).get(j, i);
                total[0] += point1[0] - point2[0];
                total[1] += point1[1] - point2[0];
            }
        }

        output[0] = total[0] / trackedPoints.get(0).cols();
        output[1] = total[1] / trackedPoints.get(0).rows();
        return output;
    }

    private static Mat img2Mat(BufferedImage in){
        Mat out;
        byte[] data;
        int r, g, b;

        if(in.getType() == BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB){
            out = new Mat(imHeight, imWidth, flag);
            data = new byte[imWidth * imHeight * (int)out.elemSize()];
            int[] dataBuff = in.getRGB(0, 0, imWidth, imHeight, null, 0, imWidth);
            for(int i = 0; i < dataBuff.length; i++){
                data[i*3] = (byte) ((dataBuff[i] >> 16) & 0xFF);
                data[i*3 + 1] = (byte) ((dataBuff[i] >> 8) & 0xFF);
                data[i*3 + 2] = (byte) ((dataBuff[i] >> 0) & 0xFF);
            }
        }
        else{
            out = new Mat(imHeight, imWidth, flag2);
            data = new byte[imWidth * imHeight * (int)out.elemSize()];
            int[] dataBuff = in.getRGB(0, 0, imWidth, imHeight, null, 0, imWidth);
            for(int i = 0; i < dataBuff.length; i++){
                r = (byte) ((dataBuff[i] >> 16) & 0xFF);
                g = (byte) ((dataBuff[i] >> 8) & 0xFF);
                b = (byte) ((dataBuff[i] >> 0) & 0xFF);
                data[i] = (byte)((0.21 * r) + (0.71 * g) + (0.07 * b)); //luminosity
            }
        }

        out.put(0, 0, data);
        return out;
    }

    private static BufferedImage mat2Img(Mat in){
        BufferedImage out;
        byte[] data = new byte[imWidth * imHeight * (int)in.elemSize()];
        int type;
        in.get(0, 0, data);

        if(in.channels() == 1)
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
        else
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;

        out = new BufferedImage(imWidth, imHeight, type);
        out.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, imWidth, imHeight, data);
        return out;
    }

    private static BufferedImage rgb2Gray(BufferedImage in){
        BufferedImage out = new BufferedImage(imWidth, imHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        Mat color = new Mat(imHeight, imWidth, flag);
        Mat gray = new Mat(imHeight, imWidth, flag);

        color = img2Mat(in); //converting bufferedImage to Mat
        Imgproc.cvtColor(color, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY); //change from color to grayscale
        out = mat2Img(gray); //converting Mat to bufferedImage

        return out;
    }

    //Converts bytebuffer to buffered image
    private static BufferedImage bufToImage(ByteBuffer pixelsRGB){
        int[] pixelInts = new int[imWidth * imHeight];
        int rowStart = 0;
        int bbIdx; //index to ByteBuffer
        int i = 0; //index to pixels
        int rowLen = imWidth * 3;

        for (int row = 0; row < imHeight; row++){
            bbIdx = rowStart;
            for(int col = 0; col < imWidth; col++){
                int pixR = pixelsRGB.get(bbIdx++);
                int pixG = pixelsRGB.get(bbIdx++);
                int pixB = pixelsRGB.get(bbIdx++);
                pixelInts[i++] = 0xFF000000 | ((pixR & 0xFF) << 16) | ((pixG & 0xFF) << 8) | (pixB & 0xFF);
            }
            rowStart += rowLen; //Move to next row
        }
        BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(imWidth, imHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        im.setRGB(0, 0, imWidth, imHeight, pixelInts, 0, imWidth);
        return im;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post some pics somewhere? I don't see why background subtraction shouldn't work if there if the camera and background are stationary.

Comment: @Mathai hey thanks for the response.  This is what I have gotten.  http://imgur.com/HYy19rQ

Comment: By the way why are you changing the image to binary? Oh I see the problem.It would be very hard to get the image of the person if he is stationary. You might want to do 'motion blob detection' instead of detecting a stationary object. Or is detection a stationary person an absolute necessity ? Thats going to be a little harder.

Comment: When you say motion blob detection, do you mean i should compare subsequent images from the video feed to each other as opposed to to comparing to my empty background image?  Also its not completely to detect stationary people as long as we follow them when they start moving.  That being said i want to make a nice AI at some point that shows our audience what the computer sees by drawing boxes or something on the original video feed.

Comment: As long as there is some pixel difference between the person and the background you can detect. For example if your shirt is white and background is also white, you will get zero as difference(black). Assuming there is some difference, you should do binary(abs(scene - background)) instead of binary(scene) - binary(background).

Comment: By the way motion blob detection is something like this - Binary(abs(Median(N frames) - scene)) . Median(N frames) gives you the background information.

Comment: Hey @Mathai When I do the binary(abs(scene - background)) i get some noise from the lighting in my room.  ie)the black spot in my throat and the noise on the roof.  Is there anyway to fix this? Is it by playing with my threshhold values and if so is there an intelligent way to pick that threshhold value or is it more of a guess and check thing? http://imgur.com/5656DZa

Comment: Post your code pls, in our qn. Whatever you have done so far. And the images.

Comment: @Mathai I have attached my code in the original question

Comment: Pixel intensities in a scene will vary when lighting changes (a person being in the room can change lighting for example), therefore its not a great idea to subtract the background in stationary scenes. Try motion blob detection or OpenCV's face or person detector but this requires that the person is upright and frontal view of face (i think) is visible.

Comment: I have face detection in there but its slow and kills my resources.  Ill try the motion blob detection.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to the question is bit late but may help for future references.

I think to learn about object detection you can look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SgWfSP6jaM) and his code [here](https://github.com/Franciscodesign/Moving-Target-Tracking-with-OpenCV) (I learn from it to do my project). And then I made my project like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kn3wFZ6piGI) based on his object detection. Or you can look for a simple background subtraction [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDWk17jqB14)